# Azure Functions Python BadHttpRequestException - Reading the request body timed out

Tags: python-3.x, azure, asp.net-core, http, azure-functions

We have deployed an Azure Function App with the Python 3.8 stack. For some requests, we have received a BadHttpRequestException

> Exception while executing function: Functions.***
> Exception binding parameter 'req' Reading the request body timed out
> due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.

But this exception is thrown from ASP .Net core . We are not sure what is causing this exception, network connectivity seems to fine.

Is it something to do with request payload size, if it is big and it resulting in slowness.

In Python Http Trigger Azure function where do set the MinRequestBodyDataRate

Comment: `But this exception is thrown from ASP .Net core .`  Is the azure function written in python to call asp.net
  What happened to the core program?

Comment: Or did this error occur in the azure function written in python?

Comment: The function is written in Python. Request not even reached to it, but we could see the error in AppInsights associated with the AzureFunctionApp... In the error log trace we could see the classes/exception which are from ASP Dot Net like "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DelayedException.Throw"

Comment: Can you recreate a sample code (without any sensitive info) for us so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just want to make sure which http request  cause the error. And have you invoked `.net core webapi` in your python azure function ?

Comment: No, .NET core is nowhere used in our logic.  What we assumed is that the underlying FunctionApp Host might be .NET core app.  Other thing we noticed was , the same request if we retry again it got succeeded.  Az Function was not receiving any inputs prior, it was idle for sometime then it received a first batch of inputs where for couple of requests it got this error